# keyboard shortcuts broken for a remote Xwindows program

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, remote-desktop

There is a remote machine, on which I login with ssh. On that machine, we have a Xwindows GUI program, namely nedit. 
All the keyboards shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for **that** program are broken (whereas other programs work just fine).

Now the weird thing is that for another user these shurtcuts work! He has the same shell (bash) and the same TERM environmental variable (xterm). But he has a mac instead of a linux laptop. The remote machine is AIX.
Do you have any hint about what might be broken?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be just this known bug.
http://www.nedit.org/faq/sect_bugs.php#NumLockBis